# Does limiting iteration count when performing permutation on a set change the time complexity?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, asymptotics

If I use a loop to perform constant-time operations (say, counting the number of times the value of the first element of the array is greater than the value of the last) over a permutation on an array of size *n*, but limit the number of iterations of the loop to a constant, does that make the big-O time complexity of my loop O(1)?

I have a feeling the answer is "yes" here, but would like to confirm.

More specifically, I'm using Python's `itertools.permutations` over an array.  To limit the total time processing the permutations, I break out of the loop after a constant number of iterations of the loop if it hasn't completed on its own.

Comment: Hey Krum, welcome to the site! It might help to specify how 'time' is in play in this scenario; could you add some more detail to your question by indicating exactly how 'time' factors into this problem?

Comment: It isn't clear what it means to "limit the number of permutations to a constant".  The only notation you introduce is $O(n)$ where $n$ is the size of a set.  The time complexity depends on the algorithm, which you only hint at as "a permutation".  Some permutations require only a "constant" number of steps, but these are special cases.  In general an inefficient algorithm to permute $n$ elements might not be $O(n)$ (much less $O(1)$), such as when the permutation to be performed is a sorting operation.